# deleting special characters from a string

Tags: java, string

okay.
this is my first post here and I'm kind of new to java
so my question is simple :
is there any instruction in java that remove special characters from a string ?
my string should be only letters
so when the user enters a spacebar or a point or whatever that isn't a letter
it should be removed or ignored
well my idea was about making an array of characters and shift letters to the left each time there is something that isn't a letter
so I wrote this code knowing that x is my string

```
char h[]=new char [d];
for (int f=0;f<l;f++)
{
    h[f]=x.charAt(f);
}
int ii=0;
while (ii<l)
{
     if(h[ii]==' '||h[ii]==','||h[ii]=='-'||h[ii]=='\\'||h[ii]=='('||h[ii]==')'||h[ii]=='_'||h[ii]=='\''||h[ii]=='/'||h[ii]==';'||h[ii]=='!'||h[ii]=='*'||h[ii]=='.')
     {
         for(int m=ii;m<l-1;m++)
         {
               h[m]=h[m+1];                 
         }
         d=d-1;
         ii--;
     }
     ii++;
}
```

well this works it removes the special char but I can't include all the exceptions in the condition I wonder if there is something easier :)

Comment: Look at the `replaceAll` method of the `String` class. This will generate a new String, but you can capture that to use it normally.

Comment: right I'm trying that
thanx mate

Comment: Good luck. There are several tutorials that can easily be found. Any further issues, I'm sure there are already several SO questions about it, so don't hesitate to do a good search, I'm sure you can find the answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said Strings in Java are immutable.
One way to catch all characters you do not want is to only allow the ones you want:

```
    final String input = "some string . ";
    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    final String permittedCharacters = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for (char c : input.toCharArray()){
        if (permittedCharacters.indexOf(c)>=0){
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    final String endString = sb.toString();
```

Comment: niiiice ^Q^ thanx

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - No, String is immutable. But you can use `StringBuffer` instead. This c ass contains `deleteCharAt(int)` method, that can be useful.

Comment: would have been better as a comment, this is not helpful in anyway.